# C#: Is my Property Within a Struct Getting In-Lined? If it is, Why is the Get Slow?

Tags: c#, performance, struct, properties, value-type

I have a struct defined like this:

```cs
public struct StringInt(string _s, int _i)
{
    this.StringValue = _s;
    this.IntegerValue = _i;
}
public string StringValue { get; private set; }
public int IntegerValue { get; private set; }
```

I've put about 10 of these into an array of StringInt[] and I loop over them trying to find a pair with a specific string and return the int of the struct.  I do this about a million times.  I would expect access to the StringValue and IntegerValue to be pretty quick, but it doesn't seem to be.  I tested in release mode with no debugger attached and here are my average timings (in ticks) using a Stopwatch instance:

(This is test code to see speeds of different accessors - note these timings are virtually identical if I'm access the int or string property.)

This method is executed 1 million times:

```
param: map = StringInt[10] with randomized values for each property.
target = string to match
{
    for (int index = 0; length = map.length; index < length; ++index)
    {
        StringInt pair = map[index];  // 27 ticks
        string key1 = map[index].StringValue; // 539 ticks
        string key2 = pair.StringValue; // 534 ticks -- just testing this
        if (string.Equals(key1,target, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) //115 ticks
    }

          return pair.IntegerValue;   // 530 ticks 
}
```

It's fast to get the StringInt out of the array, but trying to access a very simple property (which I would expect to be inlined, right?) is MUCH slower.  Is there some overhead with getting to that string?  I thought it might be the reference type killing it, but getting the integer value is just as slow.

I also tried this with public fields and also with readonly private fields backing the properties (no set accessor).  Almost the same exact results.

So -- where is that time spent?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] using https://www.nuget.org/packages/BenchmarkDotNet/ so we can repro what you are seeing.

Comment: Use a [proper benchmarking tool](http://benchmarkdotnet.org) if you want to find out exactly what time goes where, with [diagnosers](http://benchmarkdotnet.org/Configs/Diagnosers.htm).

Comment: Are you sure that `return -1` is inside the loop? Because if it's actually there, the loop is useless (it always runs for exactly one iteration).

Comment: Have you tested the same code with a class instead? Read [are structs faster than classes in general or in the .net framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1970308/are-structs-faster-than-classes-in-general-or-in-the-net-framework)

Comment: **mjwills** & **Jeroen Mostert** - I will look into that package and re-try my testing, thank you, I never heard of this as all my books just show stopwatch timings! **dasblinkenlight**- you are right - that return -1 should be outside the loop after we have not found a match -- that is how my code is, but honestly I was having a hard time formatting. **Zeohar Peled** I have not tried a class, that is a good next step to try.  I was hoping by using a value-typed struct in a very specific application, I could do better than Dictionary.TryGet, but it blows me out of the water.

Comment: @Jave the reason Dictionary can blow you out of the water is that your searching method is "linear", which is the simplest to write; but pretty badly performing (technically called "O(n)"). See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithmic_efficiency  If you sorted the values in your collection, and implemented the search using a binary search, it would be "O(log(n))" which is exponentially faster. The overall learning point here is that when it comes to complex things like performance and encryption, it's a common mistake to try to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: `which is exponentially faster.` This is likely true for large values of `n`, but not necessarily for small ones.

Comment: I understand why dictionary out did my linear search, but my collection is only 10 items.  I was hoping that I could beat out Dictionary by building something very similar but strongly typed and non-generic to cut down overhead. I never got that far.  However, tonight I was able to outperform dictionary by implementing the lookup using only an array of strings inserted such that the index of the string was the "int" value previously stored in my struct.

Comment: If the `int` values are all relatively small then an array will almost always outperform a `Dictionary`.